# Does Opera capture events by default and what is the correct behaviour?

Tags: javascript, events, opera, addeventlistener

I had some event code which failed in Opera and I have stripped it down to [this small testcase](http://jsbin.com/ulalim/edit#javascript,html,live).

Basically the problem is that the event handler doesn't run in Opera if the third parameter of `addEventListener` is not set. The value in the testcase increments in both Firefox and Chrome when the *"useCapture not set"*-button is clicked, but not in Opera.

This (old) article indicates that Opera is different than webkit & gecko browsers:
http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2006/10/12/2006-10-12-event-capture-explained. I'm not sure what to make out of it though. MDN says `useCapture` should default to `false`.

is the default `true` in Opera, is the parameter simply not optional, or what am I missing? What is the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in doubt, refer to the spec. The original and still current spec is W3C's [DOM Level 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration). Looking at the [ECMASCript binding page](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/ecma-script-binding.html), it looks as though the `useCapture` parameter is required, since there is no mention of it being optional.

DOM Level 3 Events [explicitly mentions `useCapture` as being optional](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-EventTarget-addEventListener), although I don't think this draft spec has ever reached widespread adoption in browsers.

The [relevant MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) also has a note on this:

> Note: useCapture became optional only in more recent versions of the
>   major browsers; for example, it was not optional prior to Firefox 6.
>   You should provide that parameter for broadest compatibility.

Bottom line: it's safest to always pass in all three parameters, and Opera is well within its rights to insist on it.

Comment: I guess I didn't read the whole MDN page thoroughly enough. Thanks for a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

The disparity compared with [DOM Level 3 Events](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-EventTarget-addEventListener) is a bug, and will be fixed in Opera 12.